# How to get an argument from the right side of the questionmark

Tags: .htaccess

How to redirect

/Search?Keyword=vehicles

to

**/Search.php?Keyword=vehicles**

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,NC,QSA]
```